# Is it possible to install Mono 5.18 under Ubuntu 20.04 ('focal')?

Tags: mono, ubuntu-20.04

I need the very specific Mono version **5.18** under Ubuntu **20.04** (*focal*).

However under https://download.mono-project.com/repo/ubuntu/dists/focal/snapshots/

only the snapshots for Mono **>= 6.8** are available.

Is it still somehow possible to install Mono 5.18 under Ubuntu 20.04 (focal)?

Tried to install the 5.18 Mono release from the bionic snapshot (https://download.mono-project.com/repo/ubuntu/dists/bionic/snapshots/5.18/) but this did not work out.

Comment: You can build from source code and see if that's possible. The dependencies Mono 5 relies on might not present on Ubuntu 20.04, and you might never get things done the way you wanted. Check the time stamp on https://www.mono-project.com/docs/about-mono/releases/